# Can I use Firebase Analytics and gtag at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-analytics

I have a firebase application.
I am using firebase analytics. Like that;

```js
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const analytics = getAnalytics();
```

But now client asked to add google analytics also inside **head** tag. Do I need to remove firebase analytics or both of them will work fine ?

```html
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
</script>
```

Maybe you have better solution

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When you activate **Firebase Analytics** and manually add **gtag script** both of them appear in source code. Like that;

```html
Firebase --- >
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=MEASUREMENT_ID&amp;l=dataLayer&amp;cx=c">

Script ---->
</script><script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag("js", new Date());

      gtag("config", "MEASUREMENT_ID");
</script>
```

And That's why I disabled Firebase Analytics and only keep **gtag** script.